# d3.time.format.multi is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dataset, stream-graph

I need to design a streamgraph using d3.js and I started to experiment with the code hosted on [GitHub](http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136). Since my dataset is expected to have a varying range between the minimum and maximum values for date (it can be a period of one month or several years), I decided to use multi-scale format for the ticks on my x-axis instead of fixing the format and interval into weeks, months, years, etc. For example, if I leave the tick format the same way it is given in the sample code on GitHub

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.ticks(d3.time.weeks);
```

and if the range of dates in my dataset spans for several years, the legend of the x-axis becomes crowded and unreadable.

I tried to use multi-scale format, but the visualization will not be drawn and the Dev tool of my browser returns the following error:

> d3.time.format.multi is not a function

I sincerely hope someone can suggest me a solution for this problem.

Below you can see my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.chart { 
  background: #fff;
}

p {
  font: 12px helvetica;
}


.axis path, .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 10px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>


<div class="chart">
</div>

<script>

chart("tutorial.csv", "orange");

var datearray = [];
var colorrange = [];


function chart(csvpath, color) {

if (color == "blue") {
  colorrange = ["#045A8D", "#2B8CBE", "#74A9CF", "#A6BDDB", "#D0D1E6", "#F1EEF6"];
}
else if (color == "pink") {
  colorrange = ["#980043", "#DD1C77", "#DF65B0", "#C994C7", "#D4B9DA", "#F1EEF6"];
}
else if (color == "orange") {
  colorrange = ["#B30000", "#E34A33", "#FC8D59", "#FDBB84", "#FDD49E", "#FEF0D9"];
}
strokecolor = colorrange[0];

var format = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%y");

var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 30};
var width = document.body.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "remove")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "20")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .style("top", "30px")
    .style("left", "55px");

var customTimeFormat = d3.time.format.multi([
  [".%L", function(d) { return d.getMilliseconds(); }],
  [":%S", function(d) { return d.getSeconds(); }],
  ["%I:%M", function(d) { return d.getMinutes(); }],
  ["%I %p", function(d) { return d.getHours(); }],
  ["%a %d", function(d) { return d.getDay() && d.getDate() != 1; }],
  ["%b %d", function(d) { return d.getDate() != 1; }],
  ["%B", function(d) { return d.getMonth(); }],
  ["%Y", function() { return true; }]
]);

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height-10, 0]);

var z = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(colorrange);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y);

var yAxisr = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y);

var stack = d3.layout.stack()
    .offset("silhouette")
    .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
    .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.value; });

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.key; });

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("cardinal")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); });

var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var graph = d3.csv(csvpath, function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = format.parse(d.date);
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(customTimeFormat);

  var layers = stack(nest.entries(data));

  svg.selectAll(".layer")
      .data(layers)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "layer")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
      .call(yAxis.orient("right"));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis.orient("left"));

  svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .attr("opacity", 1)
    .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
      svg.selectAll(".layer").transition()
      .duration(250)
      .attr("opacity", function(d, j) {
        return j != i ? 0.6 : 1;
    })})

    .on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
      mousex = d3.mouse(this);
      mousex = mousex[0];
      var invertedx = x.invert(mousex);
      invertedx = invertedx.getMonth() + invertedx.getDate();
      var selected = (d.values);
      for (var k = 0; k < selected.length; k++) {
        datearray[k] = selected[k].date
        datearray[k] = datearray[k].getMonth() + datearray[k].getDate();
      }

      mousedate = datearray.indexOf(invertedx);
      pro = d.values[mousedate].value;

      d3.select(this)
      .classed("hover", true)
      .attr("stroke", strokecolor)
      .attr("stroke-width", "0.5px"), 
      tooltip.html( "<p>" + d.key + "<br>" + pro + "</p>" ).style("visibility", "visible");

    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
     svg.selectAll(".layer")
      .transition()
      .duration(250)
      .attr("opacity", "1");
      d3.select(this)
      .classed("hover", false)
      .attr("stroke-width", "0px"), tooltip.html( "<p>" + d.key + "<br>" + pro + "</p>" ).style("visibility", "hidden");
  })

  var vertical = d3.select(".chart")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "remove")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "19")
        .style("width", "1px")
        .style("height", "380px")
        .style("top", "10px")
        .style("bottom", "30px")
        .style("left", "0px")
        .style("background", "#fff");

  d3.select(".chart")
      .on("mousemove", function(){  
         mousex = d3.mouse(this);
         mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
         vertical.style("left", mousex + "px" )})
      .on("mouseover", function(){  
         mousex = d3.mouse(this);
         mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
         vertical.style("left", mousex + "px")});
});
}
</script>
```

For start, I'm using the dataset from GitHub's sample:

```
key,value,date
AR,0.1,01/08/13
AR,0.15,01/09/13
AR,0.35,01/10/13
AR,0.38,01/11/13
AR,0.22,01/12/13
AR,0.16,01/13/13
AR,0.07,01/14/13
AR,0.02,01/15/13
AR,0.17,01/16/13
AR,0.33,01/17/13
AR,0.4,01/18/13
AR,0.32,01/19/13
AR,0.26,01/20/13
AR,0.35,01/21/13
AR,0.4,01/22/13
AR,0.32,01/23/13
AR,0.26,01/24/13
AR,0.22,01/25/13
AR,0.16,01/26/13
AR,0.22,01/27/13
AR,0.1,01/28/13
DJ,0.35,01/08/13
DJ,0.36,01/09/13
DJ,0.37,01/10/13
DJ,0.22,01/11/13
DJ,0.24,01/12/13
DJ,0.26,01/13/13
DJ,0.34,01/14/13
DJ,0.21,01/15/13
DJ,0.18,01/16/13
DJ,0.45,01/17/13
DJ,0.32,01/18/13
DJ,0.35,01/19/13
DJ,0.3,01/20/13
DJ,0.28,01/21/13
DJ,0.27,01/22/13
DJ,0.26,01/23/13
DJ,0.15,01/24/13
DJ,0.3,01/25/13
DJ,0.35,01/26/13
DJ,0.42,01/27/13
DJ,0.42,01/28/13
MS,0.21,01/08/13
MS,0.25,01/09/13
MS,0.27,01/10/13
MS,0.23,01/11/13
MS,0.24,01/12/13
MS,0.21,01/13/13
MS,0.35,01/14/13
MS,0.39,01/15/13
MS,0.4,01/16/13
MS,0.36,01/17/13
MS,0.33,01/18/13
MS,0.43,01/19/13
MS,0.4,01/20/13
MS,0.34,01/21/13
MS,0.28,01/22/13
MS,0.26,01/23/13
MS,0.37,01/24/13
MS,0.41,01/25/13
MS,0.46,01/26/13
MS,0.47,01/27/13
MS,0.41,01/28/13
RC,0.1,01/08/13
RC,0.15,01/09/13
RC,0.35,01/10/13
RC,0.38,01/11/13
RC,0.22,01/12/13
RC,0.16,01/13/13
RC,0.07,01/14/13
RC,0.02,01/15/13
RC,0.17,01/16/13
RC,0.33,01/17/13
RC,0.4,01/18/13
RC,0.32,01/19/13
RC,0.26,01/20/13
RC,0.35,01/21/13
RC,0.4,01/22/13
RC,0.32,01/23/13
RC,0.26,01/24/13
RC,0.22,01/25/13
RC,0.16,01/26/13
RC,0.22,01/27/13
RC,0.1,01/28/13
CG,0.1,01/08/13
CG,0.15,01/09/13
CG,0.35,01/10/13
CG,0.38,01/11/13
CG,0.22,01/12/13
CG,0.16,01/13/13
CG,0.07,01/14/13
CG,0.02,01/15/13
CG,0.17,01/16/13
CG,0.33,01/17/13
CG,0.4,01/18/13
CG,0.32,01/19/13
CG,0.26,01/20/13
CG,0.35,01/21/13
CG,0.4,01/22/13
CG,0.32,01/23/13
CG,0.26,01/24/13
CG,0.22,01/25/13
CG,0.16,01/26/13
CG,0.22,01/27/13
CG,0.1,01/28/13
RI,0.1,01/08/13
RI,0.15,01/09/13
RI,0.35,01/10/13
RI,0.38,01/11/13
RI,0.22,01/12/13
RI,0.16,01/13/13
RI,0.07,01/14/13
RI,0.02,01/15/13
RI,0.17,01/16/13
RI,0.33,01/17/13
RI,0.4,01/18/13
RI,0.32,01/19/13
RI,0.26,01/20/13
RI,0.35,01/21/13
RI,0.4,01/22/13
RI,0.32,01/23/13
RI,0.26,01/24/13
RI,0.22,01/25/13
RI,0.16,01/26/13
RI,0.22,01/27/13
RI,0.1,01/28/13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is using d3 version 2. Try using the third version instead :

http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js